# Non-multitasking devices able to resume app after close?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, multitasking

In trying to stay backwards compatible with older devices, I do a lot of testing on older iPods, some running iOS 3.1.3, some running iOS 4 but without multitasking.  Since iOS 4 came out, it seems like closing and immediately reopening my app attempts to resume from the last place (I would normally just drop the user on the first tab).  I'm assuming this is because of the ~5 second window when the app might still be shutting down, and that Apple made the decision to half allow multitasking this way on older devices.  Unfortunately, this produces negative side effects more often than not, like poor flick scrolling and crashes.

Is this the expected experience?  Any ideas on how to make the experience better for a user reopening an app?

Some notes: I do support multitasking fully for iPad 4.2, iPhone 4 4.x, etc. My app works great on all and has been accepted by Apple.  I have noticed this same problem on the iPad 4.2 and iPhone 4 4.2 when I close from the multitask bar, with the difference being that the time needed to wait before I get a fresh startup is longer than 5 seconds in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSUserDefaults and save the state at the point where the app gets terminated.

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{
 // Save your state here
}
```

This method can be found in the AppDelegate

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Like I said, I have fully implemented multitasking, so I have this and the other callbacks and willTerminate does get called when I debug.